# Prove that the distributional derivative of the Cantor function is the the $\log_3 2$-Hausdorff measure restricted to the Cantor set

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) has weak derivative equal to $0$ a.e.

Its distributional derivative should be the $\log_3 2$-Hausdorff  measure restricted to the Cantor set, but I'm having troubles doing the computation because of the peculiar definition of the Cantor function.

> How can we compute the distributional derivative of Cantor function?

Comment: It will be a measure supported on the Cantor set.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, it should be the $\log_3 2$ Hausdorff measure on the Cantor set. But how can we do the computation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the self-similarity.

You want to show that the characteristic function of [0,a) integrated against the derivative is equal to the Hausdorff measure of $[0,a)\cap C$ (and equal to the Cantor function at a). That is true for a=1 (by suitable normalization), for a=1/3 by self-similarity of the Cantor function and then true for $1/3<a<2/3$ trivially, since the function is constant on that interval.
Expand a in base 3 and use the self-similarity to show the general result.

Comment: Could you add some details? Even starting from the beginning "You want to show that the characteristic function of [0,a) integrated against the derivative is equal to the Hausdorff measure..." Your answer is not quite clear to me.

Comment: Let $\phi$ be the Cantor function and h the Hausdorff measure.Then $\phi$ is increasing and bounded and hence in BV and its derivative is a Radon measure (see Rudin, Chapter 3.5 for example), let us call it $m$.  You want to show that m([a,b))= h([a,b)) for all a<=b (or (a,b], I don't quite remember). By additivity it suffices to consider a=0. Now the measure is defined such that m([a,b))=\phi(b)-\phi(a). Proceed from there as in the first answer.