# Is there a framework where a derivative of a singular function makes sense?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, distribution-theory

Suppose we have a cumulative distribution function $F(x)$

Then by Lebesgue decomposition theorem, we may decompose $F$ into:
absolutely continuous part, singular part, piecewise step part.

As for the absolutely continuous function, traditional notion of derivative works.

As for the piecewise step part, we can make probability density "function" using the notion of Dirac delta "function".

Then what is left over is the singular continuous part.

I am wondering if there is a way to extend the notion of a function in order to take the derivative of the singular part so that it makes sense under an integral so that the fundamental theorem is saved?

For example, what would be the "derivative" of the Cantor function so that the integral of the derivative would recover the original function?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the definition of [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))?

Comment: I am vaguely familiar with what a distributional derivative is. I have worked with it in non-rigorous setting on functions like unit steps. I am wondering if it is strong enough of a tool to tackle singular cont function, and if it indeed works, how would I compute and interpret the derivative of cantor function.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176586/prove-that-the-distributional-derivative-of-the-cantor-function-is-the-the-log) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873892/derivative-of-the-cantor-function) can help.